# Rails 7 and Tailwind dynamic classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a Rails 7 app with tailwind where I'm doing something like this:

```
@list = [{name: "Some", width: "3/12"}, {name: "other", width: "6/12"}]

# In the view
<%= render 'mypartial': list: @list %>

# In the partial
<% list.each do |item|%>
  <div class="w-<%= item[:width] %>">
    <%= item[:name] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The view generates the proper HTML (`ex: <div class="w-6/12">`), but the classes are not recognized in the browser. If I hard code them without passing the variable, everything works fine. Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 5):

In case someone has the same issue, this is from the [doc](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails#class-names-must-be-spelled-out).

```
## Class names must be spelled out

For Tailwind to work, your class names need to be spelled out. They can't be programmatically composed. So no "text-gray-#{grade}", only "text-gray-500".
```

Atm, I added a list of dynamic variables in `tailwind.config.js` and it works ok, but you need to make sure all the dynamic variables are there.

```
  purge: {
    safelist: [
     w-1/12,
     ....
    ],
  },
```

Comment: This seems like a significant negative, since very often we will programmatically generate content (especially reusable) and dynamically set the css classes based on run-time values.

Answer (score 0):

Having dynamically created classes wont' work. An example:

```
# application_helper.rb

def badge(text, color)
  tag.div text, class: "… bg-#{color}-500 …"
end

# show.html.erb

<%= badge('Completed', 'green') %>
```

This won't generate the `bg-green-500` class in the build because the build process only scans the html.erb files as is, not when they are processed. So it never sees the bg-green-500 class.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the dynamic classes as a comment in your templates, if you know what options you need. I am trying this approach, since that way my dynamic styles are right next to where I use them.

Here Slim code:

```
/ To force tailwind to recognize the dynamic styles to apply
/ .hidden.pl-2.pl-4.pl-6
```

Despite the comment, meaning no render to HTML, Tailwind still picks it up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you can figure an exhaustive list of the dynamic classes you're generating, then you could whitelist them in your `tailwind.config.js` file. To illustrate, let's say you have an erb file containing:

```rb
link_to 'Show', project_path, class: "text-#{color}-700"
```

You'd just need to list your dynamically generated values, such as:

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    safelist: [
      'text-green-700',
      'text-red-700',
    ],
  },
}
```